# Directory.GetFiles not getting specific files

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

I am trying to get files with specific name however it is grabbing all the text files. below is my code.

```
string dir = @"C:\Jobs\Input"

string[] filepaths = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "JobLog*.txt");
```

This ends up getting all text files that are in the folder not the ones that start with "JobLog"

File Names:

```
JobLog123.txt
JobLog456.txt
testa.txt
testb.txt
```

Comment: It shouldn't. Can you provide the name of *other* files in your question.

Comment: I know it shouldn't but it currently is.

Comment: Clean/Rebuild your solution, This shouldn't happen.

Comment: I have done that it still happens.

Answer (score 0):

The file copy elsewhere in my code was coping all files instead of the ones that start with JobLog.

Answer (score 0):

I used code like:

```
DirectoryInfo DirInfo = ...
FileInfo[] fi = DirInfo.GetFiles("...*");
```

The various `GetFiles()` might work slightly different, just try it.